# How to get current executing method's out parameter list in c#?

Tags: c#, reflection, out-parameters

I am stuck on, Suppose I am having a method:

```
public void InsertEmployee(Employee _employee, out Guid _employeeId)
{
    //My code
    //Current execution is here. 
    //And here I need a list of 'out' parameters of 'InsertEmployee' Method
}
```

How to achieve this? one way i know

```
 MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters()
```

But how about more specific to out parameter only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// boilerplate (paste into LINQPad)
void Main()
{
     int bar;
     MethodWithParameters(1, out bar);
     Console.WriteLine( bar );
}

void MethodWithParameters( int foo, out int bar ){

bar = 123;
var parameters = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters();

foreach( var p in parameters )
{
    if( p.IsOut ) // the important part
    {
        Console.WriteLine( p.Name + " is an out parameter." );
    }
  }
}
```

---

[`IsOut` Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.isout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> This method depends on an optional metadata flag. This flag can be
>   inserted by compilers, but the compilers are not obligated to do so.
>
> This method utilizes the Out flag of the ParameterAttributes
>   enumerator.

Answer (score 4):

```
MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters().Where(p => p.IsOut)
```

Comment: Actually it is returning parameterinfo array. 'Where' not applicable somehow.

Comment: @RedSwan: `using System.Linq`

Answer (score 3):

MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters() return an array of ParameterInfo, ParameterInfo has a property Attributes - look into that to find if the parameter is out.